# Vue 2.0 with click event handler

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

How do use vue2.0 with jquery onclick event method ? As i research on the particular question with defining an mounted of this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick) on vue . but seems not really clear for me . I need an help from here. Kindly advise

As my code below jquery :

```
$(document).on("click",".ballNum li",function(){
        var robj = $(this);
        var value = robj.text();
            var bit = $(this).parents(".ballNum").attr("id");
            if(robj.attr("name")=="choice"){
                robj.removeAttr("name");
            }else{
                robj.attr("name","choice");
            }
            var isSave = saveNum(value,bit,"reverse");
            if(isSave==1){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }else if(isSave==-1){
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }else{
                layer.alert('Error',{icon: 0, title:'Alert'});   
        }
```

Comment: Vue JS natively provides all you need to do this kind of thing. It's hard to get out of the DOM mentality when you've used jQuery for years and sudden start using a JavaScript framework but I've found with Vue if you ever feel like you _need_ jQuery you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, why use JQuery and Vue? You could just do this? ```<button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>```

Comment: 100% correct @texelate

Comment: @texelate what i need is to convert this jquery function to vue2.0

Comment: It would be handy to see your template code too but basically you use `@click` as @Mick says. See the example here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers It's hard to suggest any more as you are manipulating the DOM directly — which is against everything JavaScript frameworks try to achieve. Vue should be doing this for you. You define your data, methods, etc and then let Vue update it for you.

Vue actually has a very shallow learning curve. It really pays off to spend a bit of time working through the Vue docs and you will soon grasp it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to first understand the basic difference between jQuery and VueJS. Everything that you do in jQuery can be done in VueJS, it is just a matter of understanding the difference. When we are in the jQuery land, we are habituated to the `$()` to fetch the values and stuff.

VueJS is different, here, there is reactivity at the backend, the library takes care of the complete html. You have to define the html, using the Vue syntax, then define the data array, which stores the variables. The variables are then used inside the templates

```
  <div id="app4">
      <ol>
        <li>{{todo}}</li>
        <li>{{todo}}</li>
        <li>{{todo}}</li>
  </ol>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app4 = new Vue({
        el:"#app4",
        data: {
            todo: "do something!"
        }
    })
  </script>
```

This would print "do something!" thrice.

This is the modifications we can do to the above block, after adding the input tag, here is your 'click' method, rather than use jQuery's click method, we use the one which Vue provides.

Vue's click method executes Vue's `AddToDo` function.

```
<html>
<script>
 var app4 = new Vue({
    el:"#app4",
data: {
    todo: {title: '', text:''},
    todos: [
        {title: 'Lean JS' , text: "What is JS?"},
        {title:'Learn vue',  text: "Vue has nice docs!"},
        {title:'Build something',  text: "what to build?"}
    ]
},
methods: {
  AddTodo: function (item) {
    alert(item.text + " " + item.title)
  }
}
})
</script>

<body>
<input placeholder="add title" v-model="todo.title" />
<input placeholder="add text" v-model="todo.text" />
<button v-on:click="AddTodo(todo)">Add todo</button>

<ol>
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
          {{ todo.title }} : {{ todo.text }}
      </li>
</ol>
</body>
```

What this will enable you is this:

1. create a new todo list item
2. add that todo list item in your data array, which automatically gets rendered to the html without you having to do any rendering at all.

For more details, read this: https://github.com/thewhitetulip/intro-to-vuejs/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something like this:

`<button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>`

Then in a Vue component:

```
<script>
export default {

    methods: {
        greet:function(){

              }

    }//methods
}

</script>
```

Then put your code from your method into the greet method.

But, I would start with learning some Vue.js by working through their documentation.

Mick