# Vue 2 - Click Event - Access data Attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I have done quite a bit of searching with no luck.  That is, until a moment ago when I found @texelate's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112249/vue-2-0-with-click-event-handler).

I am rewriting a page written in **KnockouJS**.  Basically, I had (in KO version) added attributes to certain parent elements.  Like `data-user-id="3"` on the outer most element.  Then say `data-project-id="x"` for each set of data within the outer parent.  Then, within the data row, on a click event I would simply use jQuery like:

```
var UserID = $(event.target).closest("table[data-user-id]").data("userId");
var ProjID = $(event.target).closest("tr[data-project-id]").data("projectId");
```

That worked great.  This does not seem to work in **Vue** on its click event.

From what I gather, this is no longer possible.  I liked the prior way, because there was no duplication of the UserID nor ProjectID.

It seems like I have to duplicate now and always pass *UserID* and *ProjectID* into my event via code?

I am not looking to change anything, it is really just to know exactly who and what I am working with.

**UPDATE**

```
editUsersTime: function (event, isReady) {
  var theDate = $(event.currentTarget).data("date");
  var prjRole = $(event.currentTarget).data("projectAndRole");
  var userID = isReady === true ? this.SelectedReadyUserID :  this.SelectedNotReadyUserID;
  alert("Date: " + date + "\nPR&: " + prjRole + "\nUserID: " + userID);
}
```

I read that `currentTarget` is to be used over `target`.  Neither worked.

The `alert` above returns `undefined` for both the `theDate` and `prjRole`.

When I pass in all of the values it works:

```
<span v-on:dblclick="editUsersTime($event, true, d, ep.projectID + '|' + ep.projectRoleID)">{{ UserReadyDaily(ep.projectID, ep.projectRoleID, d) | numeric(2) }}</span>
```

Here is the Event:

```
editUsersTime: function (event, isReady, date, prjRole) {
  var userID = isReady === true ? this.SelectedReadyUserID : this.SelectedNotReadyUserID;
  alert("Date: " + date + "\nPR&: " + prjRole + "\nUserID: " + userID);
}
```

If this is the way **it has to be** then ok.  If there is a way that is less repetitive, that would great.

**UPDATE 2**

While getting some more sample code together, which was basically reverting my code to what it was, most of it worked.  WTF.  I did reboot last night, but this is javascript, I can't imagine that did anything different.  But here is more code:

```
<table v-if="SelectedNotReadyUserID > 0" v-bind:data-user-id="SelectedNotReadyUserID" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover-blue bottomless table-footer-total scrollable">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="ep in SelectedNotReadyUser.distinctUserProjectsAndRoles" v-bind:data-project-id="ep.projectID" v-bind:data-project-and-role="ep.projectID + '|' + ep.projectRoleID" v-bind:class="{ 'is-universal': ep.isUniversal }">
      <td>
        <cite> {{ ep.clientName }}</cite>
        <span class="float-right ml-2">
          <span> {{ ep.projectNumber }}</span>
          <a href="#" v-bind:data-user-name="SelectedNotReadyUser.firstAndLast" v-bind:data-project-number="ep.projectNumber" v-on:click="doInvoiceUser" target="invoice" title="Click to Generate an Invoice based on this Pay Period, Project and User"><i class="far fa-list-alt hand"></i></a>
        </span>
        <br />
        <span> {{ ep.projectName }}</span>
        <span class="float-right ml-1"> {{ ep.projectRole }}</span>
      </td>
      <td v-for="d in DisplayDates" v-bind:data-date="d" v-bind:class="{ canedit: !IsWeekday(d) }" class="text-right">
        <!-- This is the event -->
        <span v-on:dblclick="editUsersTime($event, false)">{{ UserDaily(ep.projectID, ep.projectRoleID, d) | numeric(2) }}</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right bold">
        {{ UserProjectTotal(ep.projectID, ep.projctRoleID) | numeric(2) }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the event:

```
editUsersTime: function (event, isReady) {
  console.log("target: " + event.target);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget);
  var userID = $(event.target).closest("table[data-user-id]").data("userId")
  var parid = $(event.target).closest("tr[data-project-and-role]").data("projectAndRole");
  var datea = $(event.target).closest("td[data-data]").data("date"); // Did not work
  var dateb = $(event.target).parent().data("date"); // Worked
  ...
}
```

The console was this:

```
target: [object HTMLSpanElement]
currentTarget: [object HTMLSpanElement]
```

I am not really sure why `datea` didn't work, but seeing it was the `span`, `parent` did the trick.

Comment: Include some of the Vue specific code you've attempted.

Comment: @btl I have updated the post to give you code.

Comment: Which element has this "editUsersTime" as the click event handler? Can you show just the relevant lines of the template?

Comment: As it says in my **Update 2** it is working today.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is just a suspicion, but Vue triggers the events for child elements too. In those cases the `event.target` is the child element, not the one you specified the event handler for. So for example when you have

```
<div @click="doThis">
    <span>Click me</span>
</div>
```

and you click on the span element, the `doThis` method is called but with the `span` and not with the `div`. I think you just have your data attributes on the wrong elements.

Try to log your event target to the console to see what you're getting there.

Comment: I have added **Update 2** to my question.  Now I am glad it is working but mad that it was like this yesterday.